# What's the good practice with class constants and dependancy injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, constants

Let's say I have the following code

```
class MyLogger 
{
    const DEFAULT_KEY = 'DEF';
    const USER_KEY = 'USE';
    const BOOK_KEY = 'BOO';

    //methods dealing with logs
}

abstract class Master 
{
    protected $log_key = MyLogger::DEFAULT_KEY;

    protected do_something() {
        MyLogger::log(static::$log_key,"message");
    }
}

class User extends Master 
{
    protected $log_key = MyLogger::USER_KEY;
}

class Book extends Master 
{
    protected $log_key = MyLogger::BOOK_KEY;
}
```

MyLogger is responsible to deal with app's logs, each log has a key referencing the business object it's from
Master has methods shared with all it's childrens, one is creating a log
Each children overrides the $log_key that should be used

Now I'm having a headache trying to make it fit in good practice
I can inject MyLogger in Master's constructor, but I can't find the best way to let every children use the right log_key without importing MyLogger in each of them just to be able to get the keys constants

Comment: Why does the logger need to know about individual other classes in the first place? That's terribly tight coupling between parts which probably shouldn't know anything about each other.

Comment: That's a very good point you raise.

The first reason I did this is: using constants instead of literal strings, but I may be over applying this guideline

The second is probably laziness: if a log key changes for any reason, one change where it's defined in a constant instead of chasing literal strings all over the code, contrary to what my exemple shows, log keys don't represent classes but a business concepts/areas, and can be used at several places

But at the end the cost of having literal strings here and there compared to tight coupling of classes is probably a better choice

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use constants or strings, the point is that for every class you add, you seem to need to add one constant in `MyLogger` too. You're introducing a two-way relationship there which seems entirely unnecessary. The logger should be written in a much more generic way so it doesn't need to know about specific classes in advance, but can simply take all that information (whatever that is used for) as parameter at runtime. What if you have 1000 different `Master` classes; you're also going to have 1000 constants defined on `MyLogger`? That's insane.